# React: How to logout users when refresh token is expired while automatically logging in those that aren't yet

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-hooks, jwt, token

React Beginner Here. I'm building a feature that's logging in users automatically if they already have a refresh token recieved when they previously logged in. When the page first mounts the useEffect gets called and checks if they have a refresh token and logs them in. It also sets a use Interval to auto refresh the access tokens while refresh token is not expired. If it is expired it logs them out instantly.

**The Problem**

It's kind of like, How can you differentiate a user without refresh token VS a user that has an expired refresh token because the cookies just disappear. Code below

```js
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    const { cookie } = req.headers;
    const x = cookie?.split("hello_world_cookie69=")[1]?.split(";")[0];
    if (x === undefined) {
        return res.status(418).send({message: 'No cookie found'})
    }

// some database stuff to check the cookie and return another token
  })
```

```html
useEffect(() => {
    async function checkToken() {
      await axios.post('/check_refresh_token', {} ,{
        withCredentials: true,
        headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
      }).then(res => {
            login(res.data.accessToken);
            navigate(state?.from?.pathname ?? "/", { replace: true });
        }).catch(err => {

     // logs in and out the users
     // infinity loop here every 5s due to setInterval 
     // any of the 2 to redirect
                window.location.href = "/login";
navigate(state?.from?.pathname ?? "/login", { replace: true });



    })
    }  
    checkToken();
    
    setInterval(() => {
        checkToken();
    }, 5000)
  }, [])
            

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out lol. It was not even close to what I had in mind awhile ago. I just copied the function and pasted it out of the useEffect and made that the setInterval

```js
    function checkToken() {
        axios.post('/check_refresh_token', {} ,{
            withCredentials: true,
            headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
          }).then(res => {
                login(res.data.accessToken);

            }).catch(err => {
                if (err.response.status === 418) {
                    window.location.href = "/";
                }
        })
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        async function autoLogUser() {
          await axios.post('/check_refresh_token', {} ,{
            withCredentials: true,
            headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
          }).then(res => {
              alert("Happening")
                login(res.data.accessToken);
                navigate(state?.from?.pathname ?? "/", { replace: true });
            }).catch(err => {
                // do nothing
        })
        }  
        autoLogUser();
        
        setInterval(() => {
            checkToken();
        }, 4000) // for testing only
      }, [])
```